# Apache RewriteRule rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Alright, I give up. I just can't quite wrap my mind around apache rewrites, I've looked through a lot of the stackoverflow suggestions and none seems to make sense to me.

So, I have a script that current renders content based on www.example.com/index.php?article=some-article-name

But, I want the user to think that page is `www.example.com/section/some-article-name`

I've tried using stuff like

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/section/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

I discovered the answer thanks to the direction of all of these folks.

```
RewriteRule ^section/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ test.php?article=$1
RewriteRule ^section/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ test.php?article=$1
```

You need both to handle 2 different types of requests, ones with a / at the end and those that don't.

Comment: Does the rewrite rule work and you just need explanation?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I need one that does work and an explanation of how it does.

Comment: @JaredDrake Did you turn the `RewriteEngine on` prior to this line?

Comment: @JonathanSampson Yes sir

Comment: In your example you have `-`s in your URL but your RegEx is only looking for letters and numbers, try this: `^/section/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$`

Comment: @JonathanSampson No errors and its located in the root. I am still looking for a solid answer. I can see people hitting where my regex missed, but I still can't type www.example.com/section/some-article-name to get the actual content for www.example.com/index.php?article=some-article-name

Comment: @JaredDrake What are you using as your server? Something like WAMP, or MAMP? Have you enabled the rewrite module?

Comment: Try this ^section/(.+)$ index.php?article=$1 if the name can be anything.

Comment: Alright, I edited to try to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want a simpler rule like.

```
 RewriteRule ^/section/(.*) index.php?article=$1
```

A name like `some-article-name` will fail because you won't match the hyphen. If you want a limited regex try something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^/section/([-_.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

This will match ASCII alphanumeric characters along with punctuation most likley to be in the name.

Either of these rules will fail if you have parameters on the incoming request.

Comment: And include this guy also: 
     RewriteRule ^section/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ test.php?article=$1 (notice the extra / before the $

Answer (score 0):

Your RegEx is SO close.  You have a capturing group `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` that is looking for one or more lower case letters, upper case letters and/or numbers, but what it isn't looking for is a hyphen.  Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/section/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?article=$1
```

Because the hyphen has special significance in Regular Expressions you need to escape it.

Comment: This just sends me to the 404 page. I updated my description to try to explain myself better